# Excel VBA to add a macro to an ActiveX Control CommandButton on sheet1 of the active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have a macro which creates an ActiveX Control CommandButton as a object.

```
Dim buttonControl As MSForms.CommandButton

    Set buttonControl = _
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
            Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
            Left:=1464, Top:=310, Width:=107.25, Height:=30).Object

    With buttonControl
        .Caption = "OPEN FOLDER"
        .Name = "cmd_OPEN_FOLDER"
        .BackColor = "12713921"

    End With
```

And, I have a macro which opens a designated folder.

```
Private Sub cmd_OPEN_FOLDER_Click()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FinalFolder As String

    FolderPath = "C:\ExampleFolder1\ExampleFolder2\"

    FinalFolder = ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Value & "\"

        Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & FolderPath & FinalFolder & "", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

How can I have the Macro which creates the CommandButton also create the macro and associate it to the declared CommandButton Variable (buttonControl)?

I would like it to be on the Microsoft Excel Object module; Sheet1(Sheet1) to keep everything organized.

Comment: Do you need to create an ActiveX button? With a form button, it would be much easier, simply use the `OnAction` property

Comment: Either you copy Sheet1 from some "tempate" workbook that already has the needed code, or you generate it as described in the below answer. Note that "how do I do X?" questions normally require a [mcve] showing effort towards solving that X - as it stands  the code block in this post merely serves illustratory, contextual purpose. That said, I would avoid having underscores in event-provider object identifiers: they will cause compile-time errors once you start writing your own event-provider classes; best lose the underscore habit sooner than later.

Comment: I have edited ("ThisWorkbook") module in the past but when I implement the code I've used previously for Sheet1(Sheet1)

I have a 'Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" 

    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1 (Sheet1)").CodeModule.insertLines 34, "Private Sub cmd_OPEN_FOLDER_Click()"

line 34 is the last blank line on the code.

Comment: @FunThomas I do need it to be an ActiveX button. :) I will update the question since I realized I didn't actually explicitly state that. my apologies!

Answer (score 4):

To assign an existing macro to a shape, select it and change the OnAction property:

```
Selection.OnAction = "YourMacroName"
```

To create a new module with VBA, adapt the following VBIDE technique to your needs:

```
Private Function addModule() As String
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
With CodeMod
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    .InsertLines 1, "Sub ShowHide()"
    .InsertLines 2, "     If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(""btnHideShow"").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""Show Orders with Inventory over Safety Stock"" Then"
    .InsertLines 3, "          ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False"
    .InsertLines 4, "          ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(""btnHideShow"").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""Hide Orders with Inventory over Safety Stock"""
    .InsertLines 5, "     Else"
    .InsertLines 6, "          range(""M1"").select"
    .InsertLines 7, "          Selection.AutoFilter"
    .InsertLines 8, "          ActiveSheet.Range(""$A$1:$Q$1000000"").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=""<=12"", Operator:=xlAnd"
    .InsertLines 9, "          ActiveSheet.Range(""$A$1:$Q$100000"").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=""="""
    .InsertLines 10, "          ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(""btnHideShow"").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""Show Orders with Inventory over Safety Stock"""
    .InsertLines 11, "     End If"
    .InsertLines 12, "End Sub"
End With
addModule = VBComp.Name
End Function
```

The following will create the subroutines you want in the Sheet1 object:

```
Sub GenerateSheet1Macros()
    'assign a commandbutton, shape, event, etc to this subroutine
    addModule
End Sub

Private Function addModule() As String
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Sheet1")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
With CodeMod
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    .InsertLines 1, "Option Explicit" & vbCrLf & _
    "Sub CreateButton()" & vbCrLf & _
    "    Dim buttonControl As MSForms.CommandButton" & vbCrLf & _
    "    Set buttonControl = _" & vbCrLf & _
    "    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:=""Forms.CommandButton.1"", _" & vbCrLf & _
    "        Link:=False, _" & vbCrLf & _
    "        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _" & vbCrLf & _
    "        Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100).Object" & vbCrLf & _
    "    With buttonControl" & vbCrLf & _
    "        .Caption = ""OPEN FOLDER""" & vbCrLf & _
    "        .Name = ""cmd_OPEN_FOLDER""" & vbCrLf & _
    "        .BackColor = ""12713921""" & vbCrLf & _
    "    End With" & vbCrLf & _
    "End Sub" & vbCrLf & _
    "Private Sub cmd_OPEN_FOLDER_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
    "    Dim FolderPath As String" & vbCrLf & _
    "    Dim FinalFolder As String" & vbCrLf & _
    "    FolderPath = ""C:\ExampleFolder1\ExampleFolder2\""" & vbCrLf & _
    "    FinalFolder = ActiveSheet.Range(""N1"").Value & "" \ """ & vbCrLf & _
    "    Call Shell(""explorer.exe """""" & FolderPath & FinalFolder & """", vbNormalFocus)" & vbCrLf & _
    "End Sub"
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Note: requires a reference to the *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility* library, which must be explicitly enabled in macro security settings. Also... I'd suggest to make a single string with the needed code, *incuding* the line breaks - that way you only need to invoke `InsertLines` once.

Comment: @MBB70 I am obviously new to this kind of stuff. I don't necessarily want to add a new module if i don't have to.

Comment: @Kenny then don't add a module, just retrieve the module you want to edit from the `VBComponents` collection, eg. `Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Sheet1")`